Is the total number of data important for get endpoints?
Making a REST API with Go and PostgreSQL for a web forum project for school. I have currently already supported pagination in my get forum posts endpoint by using a simple sql query:
SELECT * FROM posts 
ORDER BY created_at DESC 
OFFSET $1 --(page-1)*count
LIMIT $2  --count

However I  am currently not returning the total number of posts which will be useful for me once I starting implementing pagination in React for the frontend using something like React Tables which needs to have the total number of pages of the data. I was wondering what are the common practice when designing GET endpoints with pagination, and should I be focused on returning the total number of rows in addition to my currently returned data? If it is, what are some ways of doing so, I know of things like tally tables but am curious to learn of other ways.

Close variants of this question have been asked and answered. Searching for [postgresql] efficient pagination will provide many answers.

Five ways to paginate in Postgres, from the basic to the exotic. As to efficient total row count, if you want the exact count you need a tally table to speed it up, or accept an estimation that's a bit off but always readily available in system views. @JohnH Please don't cross-link duplicates between tags for different RDBMS - it's all SQL, it's all similar, but there's typically a wide selection of RDBMS-specific threads.

@JohnH Im sorry if my question confused you, but my question is mainly on getting the total number of rows efficiently and not the OFFSET

@GarethT., I pasted the wrong link when I flagged the question as a duplicate (which also addresses Zegarek's comment). I was following several chains of similar questions as I searched for one that would be most helpful. Unfortunately, it looks like I forgot to copy that link.
